# Show question from surveygizmo survey using API Python

Tags: python, api, qualtrics, surveymonkey

im using an API to get some responses from surveygizmo. It works, but it is changing the question to [question(1)], [question(2)]...

```
import surveygizmo as sg

client = sg.SurveyGizmo(
api_version='v4',
# example
api_token = "api_token",
api_token_secret = "api_token_secret."
)

survey_id = "survey_id"

responses = client.api.surveyresponse.list(survey_id)

pages = responses['total_pages']

data = []

responses
```

I got the following answer:

```
{'result_ok': True,
 'total_count': 5,
 'page': 1,
 'total_pages': 1,
 'results_per_page': 50,
 'data': [{'id': '1',
   'contact_id': '',
   'status': 'Complete',
   'is_test_data': '0',
   'datesubmitted': '2020-01-22 16:07:30',
   'SessionID': '1579727226_5e28b97a9ff992.53369554',
   'Language': 'Portuguese (Brazil)',
   'datestarted': '2020-01-22 16:07:30',
   'iLinkID': '9342723',
   'sResponseComment': '',
   'responseID': '1',
   '[question(2)]': 'Sim',
   '[question(3)]': 'Assunto',
   '[question(4)]': '8',

...
```

I need to show the question as it was made. How it is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. api_version='v4' has some limitations, the question text came with api_version='v5'.